# gcc compiler optimization influences result of floating point comparison

Tags: c, gcc, floating-point, compiler-optimization

### Problem

In using automated CI tests I found some code, which breaks if optimization of gcc is set to -O2. The code should increment a counter if a double value crosses a threshold in either direction.

#### Workaround

Going down to -O1 or using -ffloat-store option works around the problem.

### Example

Here is a small example which shows the same problem.
The `update()` function should return true whenever a sequence of `*pNextState * 1e-6` crosses a threshold of 0.03.
I used call by reference because the values are part of a large struct in the full code.

The idea behind using `<` and `>=` is that if a sequence hits the value exactly, the function should return 1 this time and return 0 the next cycle.

test.h:

```
extern int update(double * pState, double * pNextState);
```

test.c:

```
#include "test.h"

int update(double * pState, double * pNextState_scaled) {
    static double threshold = 0.03;
    double oldState = *pState;
    *pState = *pNextState_scaled * 1e-6;

    return oldState < threshold && *pState >= threshold;
}
```

main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "test.h"

int main(void) {

    double state = 0.01;
    double nextState1 = 20000.0;
    double nextState2 = 30000.0;
    double nextState3 = 40000.0;

    printf("%d\n", update(&state, &nextState1));
    printf("%d\n", update(&state, &nextState2));
    printf("%d\n", update(&state, &nextState3));

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Using gcc with at least -O2 the output is:

```
0
0
0
```

Using gcc with -O1, -O0 or -ffloat-store produces the desired output

```
0
1
0
```

As i understand the problem from debugging a problem arises if the compiler optimizes out the local variable oldstate on stack and instead compares against an intermediate result in an floting point register with higher precision (80bit) and the value `*pState` is a tiny bit smaller than the threshold.
If the value for comparison is stored in 64bit precision, the logic can't miss crossing the threshold. Because of the multiplication by 1e-6 the result is probably stored in an floating point register.

Would you consider this a gcc bug?
clang does not show the problem.

I am using gcc version 9.2.0 on an Intel Core i5, Windows and msys2.

#### Update

It is clear to me that floating point comparison is not exact and i would consider the following result as valid:

```
0
0
1
```

The idea was that, if `(*pState >= threshold) == false` in one cycle then comparing the same value (`oldstate = *pState`) against the same threshold in a subsequent call `(*pState < threshold)` has to be true.

Comment: Unrelated, but why do you pass a pointer for the `pNextState_scaled` argument?

Comment: FWIW, gcc 4.8.5 for x86 produces the expected result in all cases.

Comment: I think this is [gcc bug 323](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=323) where gcc is using excess precision is a place not sanctioned by the standard. See also [gcc faq on the subject](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/FAQ#PR323).

Comment: @AProgrammer Even given a compiler bug, the code is still relying excessively on exact floating-point equality, and this is squarely in asking-for-trouble territory

Comment: @SteveFriedl, there are cases where equality of floating point is sound and not well though introduction of additional fudge factor make it unsound, especially when it is combined with inequalities like here.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude This is a stripped down version of the original code, where a structure of state variables, input variables and output variables are processed. I have not tested if using call by value would affect optimization and test result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've analysed your code and my take is that it is sound according the standard but you are hit by [gcc bug 323](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=323) about which you may find more accessible information in [gcc FAQ](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/FAQ#PR323).

A way to modify your function and render it robust in presence of gcc bug is to store the fact that the previous state was below the threshold instead (or in addition) of storing that state.  Something like this:

```
int update(int* pWasBelow, double* pNextState_scaled) {
    static double const threshold = 0.03;
    double const nextState = *pNextState_scaled * 1e-6;
    int const wasBelow = *pWasBelow;
    *pWasBelow = nextState < threshold;
    return wasBelow && !*pWasBelow;
}
```

Note that this does not guarantee reproductibility.  You may get `0 1 0` in one set-up and `0 0 1` in another, but you'll detect the transition sooner or later.

Comment: I like this a lot, though I still wonder about really close calls.  One nit and one tidbit.   Nit: `int const wasBelow = *pWasBelow;` missing the `*` ptr dereference, and the tidbit simplifies the return to `return wasBelow != *pWasBelow;`

Comment: @SteveFriedl, fixed the dereference.  I did not change the tidbit as it will detect threshold pass in both direction instead of just upward.

Comment: I found the gcc bug mentioned in research, but I was not sure if it is the same. The bug report compares the result of the same calculation, but my example really compares the same value, just stored in an intermediate variable. However the over precision issue is probably the same.

Answer (score 5):

[Disclaimer: This is a generic, shoot-from-the-hip answer.  Floating-point issues can be subtle, and I have not analyzed this one carefully.  Once in a while, suspicious-looking code like this *can* be made to work portably and reliably after all, and per the accepted answer, that appears to be the case here.  Nevertheless, the general-purpose answer stands in the, well, general case.]

I would consider this a bug in the test case, not in gcc. This sounds like a classic example of code that's unnecessarily brittle with respect to exact floating-point equality.

I would recommend either:

- rewriting the test case, or perhaps
- removing the test case.

I would *not* recommend:

- working around it by switching compilers
- working around it by using different optimization levels or other compiler options
- submitting compiler bug reports [although in this case, it appears there *was* a compiler bug, although it needn't be submitted as it has been submitted already]

Answer (score 0):

I am putting this as an answer because I don't think I can do real code in a comment, but @SteveSummit should get the credit - I would not have likely found this without their comment above.

The general advice is: don't do exact comparisons with floating point values, and it seems like that's what this is doing. If a computed value is almost exactly `0.03` but due to internal representations or optimizations, it's ever so slightly off and not *exactly*, then it's going to look like a threshold crossing.

So one can resolve this by adding an epsilon for how close one can be to the threshold without having considered to cross it yet.

```
int update(double * pState, double * pNextState_scaled) {
    static const double threshold    = 0.03;
    static const double close_enough = 0.0000001f; // or whatever
    double oldState = *pState;
    *pState = *pNextState_scaled * 1e-6;

    // if either value is too close to the threshold, it's not a crossing
    if (fabs(oldState - threshold) < close_enough) return 0;
    if (fabs(*pState  - threshold) < close_enough) return 0;

    return oldState < threshold && *pState >= threshold;
}
```

I imagine you'd have to know your application in order to know how to tune this value appropriately, but a coupla orders of magnitude smaller than the value you're comparing with seems in the neighborhood.

Comment: This allows for crossing the threshold without the event being detected.  That is probably worse for the OP than variation on the precise moment when the crossing is detected.

Comment: @AProgrammer I don't believe it allows *crossing* the threshold without being detected, because we've defined that reaching 0.0299999999 or 0.0300000001 (or whatever) is too close to count as a crossing, but if the OP's application is about *reaching* the threshold, then somewhat different logic would be required.

Comment: @AProgrammer As I think I think about this, you're probably right. If it's 0.0300000001 then it for sure has crossed if from below, though we might define 0.029999999 as having crossed as well.  This depends on the OP's application, but the general notion of not doing direct floating point equality is still mostly the guiding principle.